# I got following error When i open SiteCore website in Visual Studio 4.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I got the following two errors when I open Sitecore 6.3 website in Visual Studio 4.0:

> Error 1   The virtual path
>   '/sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/ReportRunner/DateSelector.ascx'
>   maps to another application, which is not allowed.
>   Error   2   Unknown
>   server tag 'ds:DateSelector'.

I simply install Sitecore 6.3 (website save into c:/inetpub/wwwroot/sitecoresite/website). When I open this site in Visual Studio 4.0, it shows error.

Can any body tell to me how can I open this or what mistake did I make?

Comment: [Visual Studio 4.0?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you get the error when you browse the newly installed Sitecore website, which is set up to run under ASP.NET 4.0 application pool. If that's the case, then I should inform you that [it is supported to run Sitecore under ASP.NET 4.0 application pools **starting from version 6.4.0**](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC64.aspx).

So, you have two options here:

- setup your application pool to use ASP.NET 2.0 (make sure .NET 2.0 is installed)
- upgrade a Sitecore instance to the 6.4.0+ (which might not be acceptable)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are having issues because of the way you are opening the project, there are a few issues if you open it as a File-System website project you will want to create a Web Application Project and go from there.

You can look at this blog post :
[Simplify Sitecore Visual Studio Project Creation](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/10/Simplify-Visual-Studio-Project-Creation.aspx) (or [the previous version](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/09/Create-a-Visual-Studio-2010-Project-for-a-Sitecore-Solution.aspx)) for information on how to setup a Visual Studio Project correctly for Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this might just be as simple as a missing tilde. So rather having

/sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/ReportRunner/DateSelector.ascx

you should have

~/sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/ReportRunner/DateSelector.ascx